# Android Kotlin using WebView with android_asset

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I'm using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1

I have a WebView setup as follows:

```
val wb = WebView(this)
wb.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/html/About.html")
setContentView(wb)
```

I have an asset folder setup as follows:

[asset folder structure][1]

in the project disk location:

**MyApp/app/src/main/assets/html**

but when the WebView is displayed i get

**net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

Can somebody suggest how i can access the files like this? do i have the location on disk wrong?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Ury.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use url like this `"file:///android_asset/html/About.html"`  with `android_asset` instead of `android_assets`